# As a Demon Hunter, what bonuses should I focus on when spending Paragon Points?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

As of the 2.0 patch, the Paragon point system has had a major overhaul. Now, there are four categories and each one has different things to Paragon place points in to.  As a Demon Hunter, I see a bunch of helpful things that I could be spending points on, but I feel like I'm kind of all over the place and maybe a little too spread out to see a significant overall change. There are categories such as dexterity, attack speed, reduce resource cost, crit chance, crit damage, area damage and others that all seem like viable options.

Is there an effective way to spend these points as a Demon Hunter? I realize that this may vary by build but it would be nice to have at least a general idea of which categories are more helpful than others overall for a DH. Though if you'd like to elaborate based on a certain build, feel free to do that also.

Comment: You can't spend the Paragon point on just any category you want, you have to equally distribute them among the four categories. So the only question is which of the four option you take in each category.

Comment: How you distribute it is also highly dependent on your gear. If you have a lot of crit, it might be beneficial to put them in +aspd. If you have high aspd, consider crit or crit damage. If you have high aspd you can consider putting points into area damage. If you have low hp regen consider life on hit. If you have high armor consider +armor vs +all res. The fact that you can reset your Paragon points give you more room for tweaking it to you own personal play build and preferences.

Comment: @MadScientist I am aware. But I can respec for every category which leaves me with a lot of points for each one (I'm paragon 90). I want to know how to effectively spend for each category.

Comment: Since 2.0 there's also *Damage*, *Toughness* and *Healing* stats. Why don't you just play around with your own build and see which stats give you the best bonus? Also, don't forget that 25% *FRW* is a cap *including* the paragon points(so if you have 24% already, there is absolutely no need to put more than 1% into *FRW*)

Comment: To close voters: This is exactly the type of question that we can get good subjective answers on.  Yes, it will require some degree of subjectivity.  Any answers should back up their opinions with *why* they have chosen the build they have.  These types of questions are the bread and butter of Arqade.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. What sets questions like this apart from other subjective questions is that this requires research and and a certain degree of expertise that other people will find helpful. I'm not asking for opinions, I'm asking for proven results :)

Comment: I updated my answer after 2 month of playing DH and running several built, also reaching level 70 (because that changes some of my analyse). For the record I can pretty much yolo in T6 now with my DH

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have played only (95% of the time) Demon Hunter since the Diablo 3 release and I have gathered some experience on the new 2.0 patch so here is what I think about paragon points:

- The first use of Paragon point is to **compensate the stats your DH is lacking**. You have enough DPS but can't facetank enough ? Spend your point in *Core:Vitality* and *Defense:All Resist*. Do you use a 2 hand Xbow, have a lot of Crit Damage but you can't generate hatred fast enough ? More point in Attack Speed and there you go ! On the contrary you use a Calamity  and have ~3 Attacks Per Second but you lack some crit damage ? *Offense:Critical Damage* is here for you.
- They have to **fit your build**; do you run a build with a heavy hatred-consuming skill (like Cluster Arrow)? Looks like you could use some resource cost reduction and Maximum hatred.
- Some of them are quite useless if your main focus is survivability and DPS: gold find, or life on Hit (Demon Hunters don't benefit much from LoH)
- They bring **flexibility**; you just looted a new piece of equipement that raises your DPS by 20% but you are afraid to lose 100 to all resistance ? You can compensate.

The main stats you should focus on are :

- **Core**: If you feel comfortable in damage and survivability, go for movespeed first, it will free an affixe on your boots (that can be replaced with something like +15% damage to a skill). Then Dexterity/Vitality (depending on the need) until you feel it's enough, finally Maximum Hatred.
- **Offense**: Where you lack the most. Remember that a good ratio (in total) is 1% Crit Chance for 10% Crit Damage (20/200, 35/350 etc. 10/400 or 45/150 would be innefficient). Also, your APS should be above 2,2. If you want to run a built based on sentries (with the Bonus 6 of the Maraudeur's Set) or using Vengeance you can concider cooldown reduction as a main focus (since it will help you place sentries faster).
- **Defense**: All resistance first is a must. A good T10 survivability requires at least 15 000+ Armor, ~600 000 HP (**[do not stack too much %life an neglect armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166749/24592)**) and 800+ all resistance for an overall ~12M+ toughness. Once you reach that and if you read the previous link, you can get life regen since it will increase your sustainability by **a lot**.
- **Utility**: I would focus on Resource Cost Reduction first since it's a good way to have a better ressource management (especially when using heavy-consuming hatred skills  like Cluster Arrow). Then focus on Area of Damage since it can really increase your AOE killing potential. Finally Life on Hit > goldfind (if you **really** (like **really**) need gold then you can try goldfind as a main focus but I'd advice against it).

Comment: Great answer! That one leaves nothing to be desired!

Comment: This could apply to the other classes even if I'm not following those advices with my monk, I'm focusing on getting things to replace my old gear with the new items I'm getting, which vastly differ in terms of stats from pre loot patch.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and just what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I am definitely going to reconfigure my points!

Comment: Don't underestimate the power AOE damage for clearing out large groups of trash mobs.  Secondary AOE effects from the aoe attribute can drastically boost your damage from regular aoe attacks.  I prioritized these (but then I'm a wizard: main stat/cc/AR/aoe).

Comment: @z- I've tried to put my 33 paragon point in AOE and then remove them and there was no difference in my overall dps  so I assumed AOE skills are not impacted by the AOE paragon bonus but only single target abilities and melee attack get a chance to cleave/aoe. But I might be wrong

Comment: @WizLiz I think the aoe skill only procs once per use of a skill.  So even if you cast an AOE skill, it has a single 20% chance to proc at the first hit rather than every individual monster hit, or else it'd be ludicriously good.  I proc it since its the only utility stat that contributes any amount of damage at all.  I still use LS as my wizard so I have on need for LOH, and the resource reduction (a whooping 10%) is just hilariously small to be worth it.

Comment: and the aoe does synergize well with disintegrate (and probably with rapid fire->high velocity as well).